# react-datepicker shouldCloseOnSelect doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I added a flag, but for some reason the window doesn’t close when choosing a date
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

[image]

```
   <label className="label-block">
            <DatePicker
                selected={date}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholderText="Выберите день"
                minDate={moment().toDate()}
                shouldCloseOnSelect={true}
            />
   </label>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce that in a sandbox?

Comment: omg, everything works in a sandbox, even by default, I was surprised why I didn’t find it in Google

Comment: You could have tested the [demo page](https://reactdatepicker.com/)?

Comment: I'm so stupid, I added another code, and now I understand why I had a problem, you think too, thanks bro

Answer (score 3):

keep it out of label tag easy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Might be a solution, but what if its needed like that, or the setup made so that it cant be kept out of the label?